# Is there a modern version of the Ghostzilla browser?

Tags: windows, browser

I loved Ghostzilla, a very useful tool when doing contract work on client site ;-)

But its been unusable since about 2003. Has anyone built anything similar since?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Ninja Browser](http://pr.ojectblue.com/ninja-browser/). It's based on the GhostZilla concept.

Comment: Thanks. The video looked good but the download link is broken :-(

Comment: @5arx the browser used to be known as InstaBrowser, check out the downloads here: http://code.google.com/p/instabrowser/downloads/list

Comment: Cheers. I'll give it a go.

I'm not overly hopeful about software which was last updated in 2007 but let's see what happens.

Comment: @5arx Could you tell us if it worked for you?

Comment: @BloodPhilia - I installed and tried to run it. Nada, nothing, zilch, zero :-(

Comment: @5arx darn! Ah well nice try anyway!

Answer (score 0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20060529002247/http://code212.online.fr/downloads/GhostzillaCD-1.0.1-free-v1.zip

You can still download it here. YAY!